# wamp server not work but server is online my wamp server 2.4

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

Wamp server not work but server is online and all service start. my Wamp server version 2.4 .

[http://localhost/] result is blank page. source code not view. please help me now.

Comment: Quit your skype and then again restart your wamp

Comment: Try this address `http://127.0.0.1` does that show the WAMP Homepage?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

If you have Microsoft SQL Server installed with SQL Server Reporting Services try to stop or disable this service from Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tool->Services->SQL Server Reporting Services (InstanceName)

Answer (score 0):

To start the `WampServer`, choose `start WampServer` from the `Start` menu; or run `wampmanager.exe` from the `WampServer` installed directory. An icon will appear on the icon tray. `Green` icon indicates that all the services have started. `Red` indicates that all the services have stopped. You can put the server online (so that user can access the server over the Internet) by selecting the option `Put Online`. Alternatively, you could put the server `Offline`, such that it is accessible only within the `localhost`then verify the server.may be your problem is on port problem. change the port setting (using `https://localhost:8080`) and upload your files in `www` directory.

Answer (score -1):

Start your server and then instead of this

```
http://localhost/
```

use this

```
http://localhost:8080
```

8080 is the port.

before that check weather your port is open

Comment: The Questioner did not say that they had changed the Apache port number. So this would be a waste of time.

Comment: but also it can be a solution

Comment: Only if you first tell them how to change the listening port!! Otherwise Apache will be listening on port 80 and trying to connect to port 8080 will produce an `Unable to connect` message.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like Apache doesn't have a path to the PHP interpreter.

Go to `System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Path`

Add the path to the PHP interpreter at the end of the line. Mine looks like this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;
```

Comment: This is TOTALLY unnecessary. Dont do it.